# .htaccess rewrite - redirect pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I would like to know how could I redirect all visitor who is accessing the following addresses:

https://example.com/anypage to https://example.com/search/anypage

It cannot redirect people who is already at https://example.com/search/anypage to avoid loop. This is my current .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

<IfModule mod_php5.c>  
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]    
</IfModule>    

# the following is for rewritting under FastCGI
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>    
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks    
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/search/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ search/$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

<IfModule mod_php5.c>  
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]    
</IfModule>    

# the following is for rewritting under FastCGI
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>    
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but it ruturns error 500. I was using .htaccess before, I updated my question above with more details.

Comment: Works perfeclty! Thank you very much!